# map function implementation in C

Tags: c, function

how can i implement a map function in C so I can use it in atmel studio
for example the map function arduino C
how can I use it in Atmel Studio

```
x = analogRead(A0);
y = map (x, 0 , 1023 , 0 , 2500 );
```

Answer (score 1):

From Arduino reference: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/

*For the mathematically inclined, here’s the whole function*

```
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```